# How can I make the background of an image transparent using Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have dragged an image from a website into Photoshop 7.0 in a transparent layer, but the image still has a white background.

How can I make the background of a dragged image transparent? I have tried to select it, then delete the white area. It worked but I don't want to do it manually.

Comment: What programming language do you use and what code have you tried already?

Comment: @Mary this is the wrong place to ask a question about Photoshop. Try http://photo.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks but the site it does not accept the email address eventhough my address is correct, it says invalide email address

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Magic Wand](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/11.0/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-76f6a.html) tool, set it to about 32, click in the white area and press delete.

You may need to change the layer so that it isn't a background layer (it will be labeled "Background".) To change it just double click the layer and accept the default name.

Comment: Thank you ... over a year-and-a-half-later, but it helped me solve my issue!

Answer (score 0):

Select the layer with magic wand tool (press shift for multi selection) then inverse select and cut the rest of image to make background transparent...